# on PowerPC P2040/E500mc the LD instruction EA causing kernel panic during PCI card pull out

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu-registers, powerpc

Everything I have read so far points to the fact that when accessing PCI address space during card pull out will cause kernel panic if not handled in the kernel machine_check_handler. The machine_check_handler for e500mc looks for the EA(Effective Address) of the instruction in the MCSRR0 register and compares it agains PCI address space. However, since this address (EA) was not in PCI address space, caused the kernel panic eventually, as it could not be handled in the machine check interrupt handler as the address was some bad address that was stored by CPU in the MCSRR0.

Although the GPRs are all pointing to PCI address space BAR addresses from previous cpu instructions, but the Effective Address stored in the MCSRR0 register is the same invalid physical address that the NIP is pointing to...
The MCSRR1 points to machine state (MSR) at the point of interrupt and shows LD|GLD bits set along with MCSRR1[RI] bit. so its a recoverable synchronous interrupt.

And since the CPU address access was on an external hot-plugged device we need not crash the system even if the device is not present and hence the kernel check and safe return from interrupt.

I have a few questions regarding this issue:

1. Which GPRs are used to determine the effective address of the LD instruction. The LD bit is set in MCSR register? How do I tell which addressing mode was used for generating the effective address for the LD instruction?
2. the LD instruction uses rD,rA,rB operands, how do i find which EA calculation mode is being used by the processor. Apparently there are 4 of them. Also, which GPR's do each of these operands point to? I couldn't figure it out from the E500MCRM or powepc EREF.
3. Since we are writing to PCI address space from user space, the PCI device registers are mapped to some virtual address space in the process memory to which we are writing. This is non cached mapping as far as i know.
   Does the CPU address translation to PCI device physical address, for accessing the PCI device result in bad address as the PCI device is no longer connected. My assumption for this was, since the device is no longer present the effective address returned was some junk value that caused this kernel panic. I am not sure if that's how CPU works.

Any suggestions helping my understanding are welcome. this is way deep down and beyond my expertise. I have gone through the E500MCRM, P2040RM and powerpc EREF but I cannot figure out why I am getting a bad address instead of a PCI physical address in the Effective address.

---

kernel - crash dump

---

```
fujitsu:~$ fsl_pci_mcheck_exception-> SPRN_MCAR: 0x0
fsl_pci_mcheck_exception-> SPRN_MCSRR0: 0x0f6fec68
fsl_pci_mcheck_exception-> SPRN_MCSRR1: 0x2d002
fsl_pci_mcheck_exception-> SPRN_MCAR: 0x0
fsl_pci_mcheck_exception-> SPRN_DEAR: 0x0
fsl_pci_mcheck_exception-> current->pid: [8333]
fsl_pci_mcheck_exception-> after __get_user_inatomic(inst, &regs->nip):     0x0f6fec68(inst), 0x0f6fec68(regs->nip), 0x0(ret)

Machine check in kernel mode.
Caused by (from MCSR=a000): Load Error Report
Guarded Load Error Report
Oops: Machine check, sig: 7 [#1]
PREEMPT SMP NR_CPUS=4 P2041 RDB
Modules linked in: i2cBridge(O) interruptDriver_pb(O) cma_alloc(O) hwtp_drv(O) interruptDriver_wdt(O)
NIP: 0f6fec68 LR: 0f6fec4c CTR: 0f6faad4
REGS: e4ec5f10 TRAP: 0204   Tainted: G           O  (3.8.13-rt9+)
MSR: 0002d002 <CE,EE,PR,ME>  CR: 40044442  XER: 20000000
TASK = e57dc020[8333] 'RxManager' THREAD: e4ec4000 CPU: 3
GPR00: 0f6fec4c 52afea90 52b06910 50400000 52afeb50 00000003 a0105210 52afebfc 
GPR08: a1ffffff a0000000 0000000c a0000000 20044448 1032e800 52900000 00000006 
GPR16: 0f74f434 0f729d20 135a78a0 00200000 0fe28280 52aff4b0 00000000 0fe2a6c8 
GPR24: 52afec98 0f6cd268 135a7630 00105210 52afebfc 50400000 0f71d31c 00000003 
NIP [0f6fec68] 0xf6fec68
LR [0f6fec4c] 0xf6fec4c
Call Trace:
---[ end trace 2715d0da39427f69 ]---
```

---

here's the code from fsl_pci.c that's getting called from machine_check_handler

---

```
#ifdef CONFIG_E500
static int mcheck_handle_load(struct pt_regs *regs, u32 inst)
{
    unsigned int rd, ra, rb, d;

    rd = get_rt(inst);
    ra = get_ra(inst);
    rb = get_rb(inst);
    d = get_d(inst);

    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s==> rd==0x%x, ra=0x%x, rb=0x%x, d=0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, rd, ra, rb, d);
    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s==> get_op(inst) = 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, get_op(inst));

    return 1;

    switch (get_op(inst)) {
    case 31:
        switch (get_xop(inst)) {
        case OP_31_XOP_LWZX:
        case OP_31_XOP_LWBRX:
            regs->gpr[rd] = 0xffffffff;
            break;

        case OP_31_XOP_LWZUX:
            regs->gpr[rd] = 0xffffffff;
            regs->gpr[ra] += regs->gpr[rb];
            break;

        case OP_31_XOP_LBZX:
            regs->gpr[rd] = 0xff;
            break;

        case OP_31_XOP_LBZUX:
            regs->gpr[rd] = 0xff;
            regs->gpr[ra] += regs->gpr[rb];
            break;

        case OP_31_XOP_LHZX:
        case OP_31_XOP_LHBRX:
            regs->gpr[rd] = 0xffff;
            break;

        case OP_31_XOP_LHZUX:
            regs->gpr[rd] = 0xffff;
            regs->gpr[ra] += regs->gpr[rb];
            break;

        default:
            return 0;
        }
        break;

    case OP_LWZ:
        regs->gpr[rd] = 0xffffffff;
        break;

    case OP_LWZU:
        regs->gpr[rd] = 0xffffffff;
        regs->gpr[ra] += (s16)d;
        break;

    case OP_LBZ:
        regs->gpr[rd] = 0xff;
        break;

    case OP_LBZU:
        regs->gpr[rd] = 0xff;
        regs->gpr[ra] += (s16)d;
        break;

    case OP_LHZ:
        regs->gpr[rd] = 0xffff;
        break;

    case OP_LHZU:
        regs->gpr[rd] = 0xffff;
        regs->gpr[ra] += (s16)d;
        break;

    default:
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

static int is_in_pci_mem_space(phys_addr_t addr)
{
    struct pci_controller *hose;
    struct resource *res;
    int i;

    list_for_each_entry(hose, &hose_list, list_node) {
        if (!(hose->indirect_type & PPC_INDIRECT_TYPE_EXT_REG))
            continue;

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            res = &hose->mem_resources[i];
            if ((res->flags & IORESOURCE_MEM) &&
                addr >= res->start && addr <= res->end)
                printk(KERN_EMERG "%s ==> returning from checking addresses\n", __FUNCTION__);
                return 1;
        }
    }

    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s ==> returning without checking addresses\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return 1;
}

int fsl_pci_mcheck_exception(struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    u32 inst;
    int ret;
    phys_addr_t addr = 0;

    /* Let KVM/QEMU deal with the exception */
    if (regs->msr & MSR_GS)
        return 0;

#ifdef CONFIG_PHYS_64BIT
    addr = mfspr(SPRN_MCARU);
    addr <<= 32;
#endif
    addr += mfspr(SPRN_MCSRR0);

    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s-> SPRN_MCAR: 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, addr);
    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s-> SPRN_MCSRR0: 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, mfspr(SPRN_MCSRR0));
    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s-> SPRN_MCSRR1: 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, mfspr(SPRN_MCSRR1));
    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s-> current->pid: 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, current->pid);

#ifdef CONFIG_E500
    if (mfspr(SPRN_EPCR) & SPRN_EPCR_ICM)
        addr = PFN_PHYS(vmalloc_to_pfn((void *)mfspr(SPRN_DEAR)));
    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s-> SPRN_DEAR: 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, addr);
#endif
    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s-> before get_user: 0x%x, 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, regs->nip, inst);
    if (is_in_pci_mem_space(addr)) {
        if (user_mode(regs)) {
            pagefault_disable();
           /* I am using __get_user_inatomic to get the instruction from the user
            space as any other get_user versions were resulting in -EFAULT as they can 
            sleep and this needs to be called from user context and we are in interrupt 
            context.
            */
            ret = __get_user_inatomic(inst, &regs->nip);
            pagefault_enable();
        } else {
            ret = probe_kernel_address(regs->nip, inst);
        }
        printk(KERN_EMERG "%s-> after get_user: 0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%d\n", __FUNCTION__, regs->nip, inst, ret);

        if (mcheck_handle_load(regs, inst)) {
            regs->nip += 4;
            printk(KERN_EMERG "%s-> after mcheck_handle load: 0x%x, 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, regs->nip, inst);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Do you get a backtrace/register dump when it crashes? If so please post it.

Comment: I added the following code before mcheck_handle_load as this function was not able to process the (inst) returned from get_user_inatomic or regs->nip. I decided to add this hack to see if the interrupt returns properly and the program flow continues. The E500MCRM clearly explains that LD error is a recoverable error. I still want to know how to get the proper instruction address/physical address which caused the interrupt and which GPR's are used for calculating the EA.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I added to fix the kernel panic. Looks like `regs->gpr[0]` is destination address of the LD instruction and incrementing the instruction pointer took care of the return from the interrupt context cleanly. I still have the issue of verifying that this interrupt originated due to access of PCI device address. Right now I have commented out the PCI address range check and without this check I am able to access any address without crashing the system which is even worse.

Yes. Even a null pointer access doesn't crash the system anymore. I tried it with devmem2 and accessed a nullpointer and the call goes through the interrupt and returns safely after dumping the logs from the interrupt handler.

```
regs->gpr[0] = 0xffffffff;
regs->nip += 4;
return 1;

if (mcheck_handle_load(regs, inst)) {
```